# I am not able to latch and read from an 8253 counter in mode 2

Tags: assembly, x86, emu8086, microprocessors

I am a beginner to proteus. I want to latch and read a constantly running counter in mode 2 to generate a random number between 1 and 5.

this is the emulator code. When we latch it the output gets latched and the value in AL is 11111111.

Can someone help please.

this my code:

```
mov       ax,0100h
mov       ds,ax
mov       es,ax
mov       ss,ax
mov       sp,0FFFEH
```

---

This is the main code:

```
;intialise porta & upper port C as input ,portb & lower portc as output 
mov al,00010100b
out 0eh,al
mov al,5
out 08h,al
mov al,80h
out 06h,al
mov al,00001111b
out 00h,al
mov al,00000000b
out 0eh,al

in al,08h
out 02h,al
mov al,11111111b
out 02h,al

xi: jmp xi
```

Comment: IIRC, the count value written does not propagate into the counter until the next clock pulse. So you may be latching too early. Try a delay. Besides, without a (random length) delay between starting and latching the counter, the timer will be useless as a random generator.

Comment: Yeah I am using the user's button click as a random length. We tried a delay after loading and also after latching. It doesn't work.

Comment: Please edit your question and make that clear in the code sample. Another question: why `mov al,11111111b / out 02h,al`? Aren't you overwriting the result of `in al,08h / out 02h,al` there?